# Switching user to root or parent directory ,logging in via windows

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

I have a linux server which i use to host file , there are multiple users to access different folders on the server. i have a user 'ftp_user' whose by default landing location is '/data/myworld/' i have made a folder at '/data/shared/' although navigation can be to /data/shared can be done via command line or ftp software but my user 'ftp_user' wants to access this folder(/data/shared/) using windows simple command of ftp:/user:ip/data/shared/ but he cannot access to /data/shared becuase by default he is landing into /data/myworld/ so this extra /data/shared is trying to find a folder with absolute path of /data/myworld/data/shared , i am looking for '..' or '/ root' in microsoft windows. Kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

Set up a linux user with the path /data/shared and login to ftp with this user

Most ftp servers prevent path traversal above the "landing point"

If you want to remove this protection the exact method depends on the particular ftp server software being used

This is more a question for "superuser" or "serverfault" than "stackoverflow"

Comment: this is a shared path and cannot be the landing location for users as user like to land at there own folder by default , they can should only go to shared path if they want to not by deafault .

Comment: As my answer says, "that's the way it is" by default with most ftp server software.  It needs configuration changes that are specific to the type of software used to alter this.  I suggest you re-ask on serverfault with details of the exact Linux distribution (ie Ubuntu 12.04) and the ftp server software (ie proftpd-basic_1.3.4 )